# TableView created via fxml not populating

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am trying to add a TableView control to a pre-existing application. I am trying to copy the following example code (which runs perfectly):

```
public class FxTableViewExample1 extends Application {

    private TableView<TransitionRow> outputTable;
    private ObservableList<TransitionRow> data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Table View Example 1");

        // Table view, data, columns and properties
        outputTable = new TableView<TransitionRow>();
        data = getInitialTableData();
        outputTable.setItems(data);

        TableColumn col1 = new TableColumn("Harland");
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, Double>("scaleY"));

        TableColumn col2 = new TableColumn("Gradstein");
        col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, Double>("gradsteinAge"));

        TableColumn col3 = new TableColumn("Label");
        col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, String>("oldName"));

        outputTable.getColumns().setAll(col1, col2, col3);
        outputTable.setPrefWidth(450);
        outputTable.setPrefHeight(300);

        // Vbox
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));;
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(outputTable);

        // Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 500, 475); // w x h
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Select the first row
        outputTable.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        TransitionRow tr = outputTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(tr);
    }

    private ObservableList<TransitionRow> getInitialTableData() {
        List<TransitionRow> list = new ArrayList<>();

        TransitionRow tr1 = new TransitionRow();
        tr1.setScaleY((Double) 124.567d);
        tr1.setGradsteinAge((Double) 130.001d);
        tr1.setOldName("Stuff");

        TransitionRow tr2 = new TransitionRow();
        tr2.setScaleY((Double) 456.546d);
        tr2.setGradsteinAge((Double) 123.768d);
        tr2.setOldName("Other stuff");

        list.add(tr1);
        list.add(tr2);

        ObservableList<TransitionRow> data = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        return data;
    }
}
```

My app is made via SceneBuilder with separate controller classes. When I tried to integrate the above example the table did not populate so I have created the following minimal example to demonstrate my problem:

[Test1Run.java]

```
public class Test1Run extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Test1.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Test1");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[Test1.fxml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" fx:controller="experimental.tableview.Test1Controller">
    <TableView fx:id="outputTable" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="569.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="17.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="col1" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col2" prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col3" prefWidth="75.0" text="C3" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

[Test1Controller.java]

```
public class Test1Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TableView<TransitionRow> outputTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<TransitionRow, Double> col1;
    @FXML private TableColumn<TransitionRow, Double> col2;
    @FXML private TableColumn<TransitionRow, String> col3;

    private ObservableList<TransitionRow> data;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        outputTable = new TableView<TransitionRow>();

        col1 = new TableColumn<TransitionRow,Double>("Harland");
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, Double>("scaleY"));

        col2 = new TableColumn<TransitionRow,Double>("Gradstein");
        col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, Double>("gradsteinAge"));

        col3 = new TableColumn<TransitionRow,String>("Label");
        col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, String>("oldName"));

        // This line should cause the column names on the GUI to change. They don't.
        outputTable.getColumns().addAll(col1, col2, col3);

        data = getInitialTableData();

        // This line should cause rows of data to appear on the TableView. It doesn't.
        outputTable.setItems(data);

    }    

    private ObservableList<TransitionRow> getInitialTableData() {
        List<TransitionRow> list = new ArrayList<>();

        TransitionRow tr1 = new TransitionRow();
        tr1.setScaleY((Double) 124.567d);
        tr1.setGradsteinAge((Double) 130.001d);
        tr1.setOldName("Stuff");

        TransitionRow tr2 = new TransitionRow();
        tr2.setScaleY((Double) 456.546d);
        tr2.setGradsteinAge((Double) 123.768d);
        tr2.setOldName("Other stuff");

        list.add(tr1);
        list.add(tr2);

        ObservableList<TransitionRow> results = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        return results;
    }
}
```

I want it to look like FxTableViewExample1:
[image: Screenshot of working example]

But instead it looks like this:
[image: Result of broken code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `initialize` you work with new the `TableView` that you create in the first statement.

You never add this table to the scene though...

The following code should work, assuming the `TransitionRow` class contains suitable methods for `PropertyValueFactory` to work.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    col1.setText("Harland");
    col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, Double>("scaleY"));

    col2.setText("Gradstein");
    col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, Double>("gradsteinAge"));

    col3.setText("Label");
    col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TransitionRow, String>("oldName"));

    data = getInitialTableData();

    outputTable.setItems(data);
}
```

Comment: I edited "initialize" as you suggested and it made no difference? 
Also I don't understand what you mean by "adding to the scene". Surely the tableview is created via SceneBuilder/fxml and I only want to configure and a data to it?

Comment: Also I assume TransitionRow has the right methods as it works perfectly with PropertyValueFactory in the first code snippet: FxTableViewExample1

Comment: @Ralph I just tested the code with my modifications and it works... There must be something wrong that you havent posted any information about... By *"adding to the scene"* adding a code to a parent that is/becomes a descendant of the root of the scene or to that root itself, which you're not doing when you override the field's value.

Comment: Apologies I missed removing one of the col = new TableColumn statements when I copied and pasted from your answer. Have corrected my carelessness and it now works perfectly :-) And thank you for the extra explanations.